# migrate is showing validation error while adding datetime field in django 1.8

Tags: python, django-1.8

I have following model in models

```
class UserTripbook(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    country = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    social_status = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    place_name = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    tripped_with = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    tripped_by = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    image_url = models.ImageField(upload_to = upload_path, max_length = 300, blank = True, null = True)
    image = models.CharField(max_length = 200, blank = True, null = True)
    experience = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    rating = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
```

It's working fine and i have created some entries also in database using my application but now when i add

```
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

in my model and run makemigrations, it works but after that when i run migrate command, it throws validation exception:
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: [u"'NULL' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]

I have tried django.utils.timezone.now and datetime.now also as default but same error. Then i thought maybe it's because i already have some data in my database so i deleted all rows from database manually and ran migrations and migrate command but still same error.
I think it's not the model but some setting is required to solve this but not sure.
Just FYI, i have added DATETIME_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
also in settings file . Please guide me to solve this.

Comment: I am facing this problem even when I delete this 'created' column and running migrations

Answer (score 0):

Your date field has null values, you can avoid the error by doing:

```
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, null=True)
```

This will allow `Null` values in the datetimefield.
You can overwrite the null values manually later.